# MYSQL: How to use outer aliases in subquery properly?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, subquery, alias

The first query works just fine. It returns one row from the table 'routepoint'. It has a certain 'route_id' and 'geo_distance()' is on its minimum given the parameters. I know that the subquery in the FROM section seems unnecessarily complicated but in my eyes it helps to highlight the problem with the second query.

The differences are in the last two rows.

```
SELECT rp.*

FROM routepoint rp, route r, (SELECT * FROM ride_offer WHERE id = 6) as ro

WHERE rp.route_id = r.id
AND r.id = ro.current_route_id
AND geo_distance(rp.lat,rp.lng,52372070,9735690) = 

(SELECT MIN(geo_distance(lat,lng,52372070,9735690)) 
FROM routepoint rp1, ride_offer ro1 
WHERE rp1.route_id = ro1.current_route_id AND ro1.id = 6);
```

The next query does not work at all. It completely freezes mysql and I have to restart.
What am I doing wrong? The first subquery returns excactly one row. I don't understand the difference.

```
SELECT rp.*

FROM routepoint rp, route r, (SELECT * FROM ride_offer WHERE id = 6) as ro

WHERE 
rp.route_id = r.id
AND r.id = ro.current_route_id
AND geo_distance(rp.lat,rp.lng,52372070,9735690) = 

(SELECT MIN(geo_distance(lat,lng,52372070,9735690)) 
FROM routepoint rp1 
WHERE rp1.route_id = ro.current_route_id);
```

Comment: How big is the routepoint table? Also, have you compared the execution plan of the two statements?

Comment: You're trying to write a dependent subquery - the subquery will be executed once per row of the outer query's result set, and this will be terribly slow if you have a lot of rows - you'll want to optimize your subquery as much as you can.

Comment: @Klas the routepoint table has about 14k of rows and it will become much bigger.

Comment: @Romain which resultset is that? Every combination of the 3 tables or every combination fitting the prior WHERE clauses?

Comment: @Nielow MySQL will first apply all filters that don't require the dependent subquery be executed. If the predicate is still `TRUE` at this point, then the subquery will be evaluated. This may however screw up some levels of optimization - mysql isn't terribly good at dependent subqueries.

Comment: Implicit join syntax was defined in SQL '89. It is superseded by SQL '92 explicit join syntax. Since that time implicit join are an anti-pattern, because it's too easy to do accidental cross joins and it hard to see the join criteria between all the other where clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as pointed out by Romain, that this is costly.

[This article](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html) describes an algorithm that reduces the cost by a 2-step process.

Step 1: Find a bounding box that contains at least one point.

Step 2: Find the closest point by examining all points in the bounding box, which should be a comparatively small number, thus not so costly.